# quota with transmission daemon?

Tags: quota, transmission

I just installed a seedbox with Transmission daemon on a Debian 9 server. 
My Local disk space is 457.69 GB total / 428.30 GB free / 29.39 GB used

When I connect to my seedbox in RPC with Transmission Remote GUI, the free space is 12.08 GB.
My torrents are correctly downloaded and uploaded. But why the free space of the transmission daemon process is not the same than global Local disk space.

I do not set quota information. I just let the default value on a fresh server.

Where do I have to search the issue ? User quota, folder quota, mount quota ? Im not specialist at all with linux environment :)
Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. This should be moved to [su]

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for this notification

Answer (score 0):

in fact it was in my default debian installation .. :

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   511M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0  19.5G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0 445.2G  0 part /home
└─sda4   8:4    0   511M  0 part [SWAP]
```

All my space is in /home
Thanks for everyone ;)